# Comparing with nil error in quicksort

Tags: ruby, quicksort

I'm trying to write quicksort in Ruby, but I get an error that says:

```
qsort.rb:43:in `<': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
from qsort.rb:43:in `block in dist'
from qsort.rb:42:in `each'
from qsort.rb:42:in `dist'
from qsort.rb:32:in `sort'
from qsort.rb:34:in `sort'
from qsort.rb:53:in `<main>'
```

This is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/ruby

class QArray
  @data = []
  @pvalue
  @less 
  @more


  def initialize(arr = [])
    @data = arr
    @pvalue = @data[0] unless @data.empty?
  end

#these methods are so I can treat a QArray like a regular array
  def push(value)
    @data.push value
  end
  def empty?
    @data.empty?
  end

  def single?
    return @data.size == 1
  end

  def print
    puts @data
  end
  def sort
    puts "starting the sort with an array of #{@data}"
    dist unless @data.empty?
    @less.sort unless @less.empty? || @less.single?
    @more.sort unless @more.empty? || @more.single?
    @data = @less + @more #combine the two arrays again
  end

  def dist
  #distributes values into subarrays
    @less = QArray.new
    @more = QArray.new
    @data.each {|e| 
      if (e < @pvalue) 
    @less.push e
      else #includes both equals and greater than
    @more.push e
      end
    }
  end
end

arr = QArray.new ([1,5,6,7,9,23,43,2,4,6])
arr.sort
arr.print
```

I'm guessing that this is related to e being nil in the block.  However, this shouldn't happen, because I check whether the array is empty before I call dist.

Why do I get this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create new `QArray`s in `dist`.

You initialize `@pvalue` on `QArray` creation, but they're empty when created in `dist`.

In `dist` you then try to use `@pvalue`, which is nil, because you create the array empty and only *then* add values to it, never updating the uninitialized `@pvalue` value.

Unrelated, but what are those class instance variables at the top of `QArray` for?!

Comment: Those are class variables?  Ha, ha, I'm kind of new to ruby, and I thought those were how you declared your instance variables.

Comment: @jwcoding You don't "declare" instance variables in Ruby; they just exist when used for the first time.